# Direct php.ini error_log and access_log to stdout

Tags: php, docker

I want to direct error_log and access_log in php.ini to stdout. My OS is windows 10. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it that you wish to view all the errors in real-time in a console?
If so you can just keep an active watch on the error_log file with  powershell ( get-content file -wait )

Comment: Yes. My php is inside a windows docker container. I want to use `docker logs` to view the logs.

Answer (score 3):

To output logs in docker, write them to `/dev` IE:

```
error_log /dev/stderr
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Note that, when it comes to the [official `php` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php), action is no longer required:

- For `php:<version>-apache`, error logs are [automatically redirected to `/dev/stderr`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/3074b80a38201143a7938fb355c918ca109062d7/8.1/buster/apache/Dockerfile#L85).
- For `php:<version>-fpm`, error logs are [automatically redirected to `/proc/self/fd/2`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/3074b80a38201143a7938fb355c918ca109062d7/8.1/buster/fpm/Dockerfile#L245). This has the same effect as above, but [with a few less layers of indirection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/564084).